# Conditional mocking: Call original function if condition matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

A very similar question was asked, however it doesn't answer my doubt.

```
@mock.patch('myget.myvalue.myfrom.myAPI')
def test_thatdoesntwork(myAPI_mock):
   orig_function = myget.myvalue.myfrom.myAPI
   nth_value = get_valuefrom_myDB(n=111)
   def mock_function_for_nth_value_only(myvalue):
            if myvalue == nth_value:
                return get_valuefrom_myDB(n+1) 
            else:
                return orig_function(n)

   nplus1th_value = get_valuefrom_myDB(n=112)
   myvalue =  myget.myvalue.myfrom.myAPI(nplus1th_value)
   # getting "CRITICAL: maximum recursion level exceeded"
```

am assuming when I call orig_function , I am actually calling the mocked function, and that causes the CRITICAL recursion error....
but what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The `@mock.patch` decorator replaces the function before your code starts, so `orig_function = myget.myvalue.myfrom.myAPI` already points to the mocked version.

Instead, you can use the context manager to ensure that you only replace the function in the scope you want.

This test version should work better for you:

```
def test_that_works():
    orig_function = myget.myvalue.myfrom.myAPI
    nth_value = get_valuefrom_myDB(n=111)

    def mock_function_for_nth_value_only(myvalue):
        if myvalue == nth_value:
            return get_valuefrom_myDB(myvalue + 1)
        else:
            return orig_function(myvalue)

    with mock.patch('myget.myvalue.myfrom.myAPI',
                    side_effect=mock_function_for_nth_value_only):
        nplus1th_value = get_valuefrom_myDB(n=112)
        myvalue = myget.myvalue.myfrom.myAPI(nplus1th_value)
```